# Is there a script to show mathematical symbols in java script?

Tags: javascript, math

[image]

I wanna to show mathematical symbols in my form, is there a script doing that?

//some code

Like this image:

[image]

Comment: images don't load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your symbols are limited with pure html, some are:

```html
<p>I will display &sum;</p>
<p>I will display &minus;</p>
<p>I will display &times;</p>
<p>I will display &radic;</p>
<p>I will display &int;</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_math.asp">SOURCE</a>
```

If you are serious though, consider using this library (it has startup docs):

https://www.mathjax.org/

with the docs at:

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html

you can simply do this (with mathjax):

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

and then enter math strings like this:

```
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
```

One of their examples is:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<div>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</div>
```

(sorry, i couldnt see the image you posted, it wouldnt load)

Anyways, hope this helps!

Comment: i wanna special math symbols as 
Modulation and permutation symbols , ....

Comment: Yes, MathJax has all of the math symbols, look at the link near the bottom